# Lync PowerShell Script not working

Tags: powershell, csv, lync-2010, lync-2013

I am in process of moving users in batches from one Lync Server pool to another, this requires me to have a CSV with the user names of the one I want to move. For someone famililar with PowerShell should be able to see that I am giving it the csv file name, and then importing the file in userarray after that I want to remove the "+" symbol from the user LineURI. i.e: from tel:+5556667777 I want that to change to tel:5556667777, then I want to change the dial plan for the user and lastly I want to migrate the user from pool X to pool Y.

While it all seemingly should work, when I run the script it blanks out/erases the LineURI of the people I intend to migrate, I obviously don't know what I am missing some guidance will be appreciated.

Update: Fixed and here is how:

```
 $File = "C:\Location\users.csv"

 $UserArray = Import-CSV -Path $File
 $transcriptname = "F:\Transcript\Users_Logs" + `
(Get-Date -format s).Replace(":","-") +".txt"
 Start-Transcript $transcriptname

 Foreach ($user in $UserArray)
{

$Tel = Get-CSUser -Identity $user.SAMAccountName
$URI = $Tel.LineURI 
#$TelNew = $URI.Replace("tel:+", "tel:")
$TelNew = $URI.Replace("+", "")
  Get-CSUser -Identity $user.SAMAccountName
  Set-CSUser -Identity $user.SAMAccountName -LineURI $TelNew 
  Grant-CSDialPlan -Identity $user.SAMAccountName -PolicyName "New_Dial_Plan"
  Move-CsUser -Identity $user.SAMAccountName -Target new.pool.com -confirm:$false
  Get-CSUser -Identity $user.SAMAccountName
}


Stop-Transcript
```

The users.csv has to be in the format:

First line should have the word SAMAccountName and the subsequent lines the user ID's i.e:

SamAccountName
UserID1
UserID2
UserID3...

Comment: Upon a little more digging around it looks like that the user accounts are getting pulled in in the incorrect format (or what seems like). For instance the CSV File is listed like: SAMAccountName and then the subsequent lines have user ID's .. and when I do a Write-Host I see that the valules are getting pulled in as: @{SamAccountName=User1} @{SamAccountName=User2} .. I am not sure if that is right.

Comment: Can you give an example of your CSV file ?